# Can I carry out a Propensity Score Matching with a general population of 90 observations and a treatment group of 20?

Tags: small-sample, propensity-scores, matching, treatment-effect

My population consists of 90 administrative zones that divide the city. Of those zones, only 20 received the treatment. After carrying out PSM, I have 17 zones in the treatment group and 17 in the control group, with a high level of balance on co-variables.

I know scholars recommend a minimum of 100 observations in each group, but considering the size of my population of interest  (90), is it okay if I proceed with my research? I have already invested a substantial amount of work getting this far.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use PS weighting instead of PS matching in this case. The benefit of weighting is that you will not exclude any observations from your analysis and probably also get a better balance.

If you are sure you want to use PS matching you might also think of 3:1 matching or 2:1 matching dependent on you data. You should keep in mind that you are loosing statistical power for each observation you exclude from the analysis. So you can of course do the rest of your analysis with 34 observations, but it might be very hard to detect any effect.

I hope that helped you a little bit.